# What does Twitter's architecture diagram looks like?

Tags: java, twitter, architecture, diagram

I'm building a service somewhat like Twitter and in the process of creating the design.

I looked at Twitter's open source projects on [github](http://twitter.github.io/), and on some alternative open source projects for part of the design [example](http://blog.process-one.net/introducing_the_xmpp_application_server_the_twitter_example/)

So I have a general idea of what is needed to accomplish my task.
I failed to find Twitters actual architecture diagram or an article containing an overview about it.

What does Twitter's architecture diagram looks like?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It would be difficult to find a single, grand architecture diagram explaining all Twitter services. However, you can find high level overviews and articles dealing with specific parts of it.

An overview from a Twitter engineering lead is [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/06/Twitter-Architecture).

You can follow the [Twitter engineering blog](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering) for updates.

This [video](http://ontwik.com/rails/oreilly-oscon-java-2011-raffi-krikorian-twitter-from-ruby-on-rails-to-the-jvm/) is about their move from ROR to the JVM.

A [list](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/14/twitter-by-the-numbers-460000-new-accounts-and-140-million-t.html) of Twitter scale numbers.

An article on [tweaking](http://highscalability.com/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster) Twitter's architecture.

[This one](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/12/19/how-twitter-stores-250-million-tweets-a-day-using-mysql.html) deals with their storage backend.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [updated architecture](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html) and details about some of the design decisions.  Its interesting note that Twitter is using a write intensive architecture to make read perform better (O(1) infact).  The [highscalability](http://highscalability.com/) article points to the original Infoq presentation.

Comment: This answer is more current then the first one

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great overview as of 19 Jan 2017 in case anyone else happens upon this thread.  It covers lessons learned and the evolution of their various data solutions over time.

[Infrastructure Behind Twitter](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/infrastructure/2017/the-infrastructure-behind-twitter-scale.html)